# Using jQuery drag and drop to vote

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, drag-and-drop

I'm using jQuery's drag and drop plugin, and here's what I'd like to do.

I have 3 containers.

`[Droppable 1] [Draggable] [Droppable 2]`

`Number: 3 ----------------- Number: 5`

Under [Droppable 1] and [Droppable 2], there will be a current number, stored in one of my tables. I'd like to be able to take the [Draggable] and drop it to either [Droppable 1] or [Draggable 2] and from there, it will update (increment) the number with some ajax and maybe the jQuery fade function.

The problem is, I'm not sure what I need to do to bind the specific vote to the specific Droppable container. I'd also like to restrict the user from voting more than once, but I suppose I can dig around to figure that out.

I've been asking around in #jquery on freenode, but I've been getting ignored. Maybe this is too basic, but I'm such a jQuery noob.

Answer (score 0):

How about using one of the star rating plugins available?  You can drag the number of stars to rate the (item) and then work out the average from there.

You can also drag by half star and replace the stars with other images.

Or you can use a jQuery slider plugin to drag from low to high

Comment: Well, it's not really going to use a star rating system at all. Just an increment++ each time the [Droppable] container accepts the [Draggable] image.